# React router dom return blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

In `App.js`, I tried `react-router-dom`, but it returns blank page. I tried to add (`exact`) and I also added the (`Switch`) but nothing worked and to be mentioned that I also replaced (`component`) with (`element`) but nothing worked.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css"
import Header from "./header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Apps from "./Apps";
import Games from "./Games";
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";
import BookData from "./Data.json";
import { Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <div className="App">
          <SearchBar placeholder="Enter App Name..." data={BookData} />
        </div>
        <Apps />
        <Footer />
        <Route path="/games" element={<Games />} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: The `Route` component should be rendered by a `Routes` component. Is this your [mcve]? Are you actually using `react-router-dom@6`?

Comment: Try setting a route to go to the root. <Route path="/" element={<Games />} />

Comment: To be honest, you're saying it's returning a blank page. But did you see the console?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly isn't working. Just about anything *other than* "it's not working" is helpful to us trying to help you. Are there any console errors?

Comment: What is the version of React Router Dom you are using ??

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react-router-dom v6. You should wrap the individual route inside `<Routes></Routes>`. Try the below code,

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css"
import Header from "./header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Apps from "./Apps";
import Games from "./Games";
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";
import BookData from "./Data.json";
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Routes } from "react-router-dom"

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <div className="App">
          <SearchBar placeholder="Enter App Name..." data={BookData} />
        </div>
        <Apps />
        <Footer />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/games" element={<Games />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

If you are using react-router-dom v5. You should wrap the individual route inside `<Switch></Switch>`.

Comment: If OP was using RRDv6 then surely they'd be mentioning the failed build and console errors caused by a failed invariant check since the `Route` wasn't rendered in a `Routes` component. Also, with only a single route using a `Switch` in RRDv5 is kind of useless.

Answer (score 0):

As I believe you can only place `Route` component inside `browseRouter` component
like:

```
   <div>
     <Header />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div><div/> //this is not allowed inside BrowseRouter 
        <Route path="/games" element={<Games />} />
        <Route path='/component' element={<component/>}
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
```

Comment: We can pass whatever children to `<BrowserRouter/>`. And the `<Route>` component should be wrapped inside `<Routes>`